# Bash: check if the current directory is a Git Repository

Tags: linux, bash, git, terminal, xfce

I have a color schema for my `XFCE terminal` and I try to set the branch name and color when I'm inside a directory which is a `Git Repository`.

Actually this is the configuration of my bash:

`PS1="\u@\h $(if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then echo '\W'; else echo '\w'; fi) \$([[ \$? != 0 ]] && echo \":( \")\$ "`

and when I'm inside a directory which is a Git Repository I want to show that:

`[\u@\h \W]\[\033[00;32m\]\$(git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$`

this is the `git_branch function`:

`git_branch() { git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/' }`

I tried to edit the `PS1` as that:

`\$(if [[git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree]]; then [\u@\h \W]\[\033[00;32m\]\$(git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$`

but it isn't working - when I'm inside the directory of Git repository, it doesn't show me the name of the branch.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does "it isn’t working" mean?

Comment: When I'm in a git directory it doesn't show me the name of the branch.

Comment: `if [[...]]; then [\u@\h \W]` will attempt to run a command with the name `[\u@\h`.

Comment: Here's what I do: https://github.com/wrp/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc#L74

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell! After edited it like that `PS1="$(if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then echo '\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \W'; else echo '\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w'; fi) \$([[ \$? != 0 ]] && echo \"\[\033[01;31m\]:(\[\033[01;34m\] \")\\$\[\033[00m\]) \$(if [[git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree]]; then [\u@\h \W]\[\033[00;32m\]\$(git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$"` I receive that error `bash: command substitution: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: Also : look for the `__git_ps1` function in the `contrib/` files of your git installation, either in `contrib/completion/git-completion.bash` or in `contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh`

Comment: How can I concatenate it to my actual configuration?

Answer (score 2):

To check if the directory is under git control, you can source the following snippet:

```
# mygitprompt.sh
PROMPT_COMMAND="CheckIfGitDir"

CheckIfGitDir()
{
    if git status &>/dev/null; then
        echo "Directory is under the control of git"
    else
        echo "There is no sign of git anywhere"
    fi
}
```

How to source:

```
source /path/to/mygitprompt.sh
```

Everytime you hit ENTER, the command in `PROMPT_COMMAND` will be executed.